# Предоставление прав на выполнение различных операций кода

Tags: python

Как в python предоставлять или забирать различный права у исполняемого кода. 
Я хотел бы реализовать проверку учебных проектов, т.е. преподаватель пишет задание и xUnitTest, ученик выполняет задание. Имеется некоторая система, которая загружает код и выполняет тест. Как в python можно было бы проконтролировать, что ученик не полезет в файловую систему, сеть, запустит выполнение приложения и т.п.
Решаются ли подобные задачи средствами python или есть иные пути решения?

Answer (score 0):

**chown/chmod** на файлы/папки куда ученику лезть не надо! Иными словами - работайте с правами доступа! Этого будет достаточно!

Comment: Спасибо. А запуск исполняемого кода  из скрипта? Системные вызовы?

Comment: @АлександрВербицкий ``Приложения пользователя не могут непосредственно выполнять код ядра. Они не могут просто вызвать функцию, которая существует в пространстве ядра, так как ядро находится в защищенной области памяти. Если программы смогут непосредственно читать и писать в адресное пространство ядра, то безопасность системы "всё". Пользовательские программы должны каким-либо образом сигнализировать ядру о том, что им необходимо выполнить системный вызов и что система должна переключиться в режим ядра, где системный вызов должен быть выполнен с помощью ядра, работающего от имени приложения.``

Comment: @АлександрВербицкий по поводу системных вызовов - вам очень поможет эта статья: http://www.okbsapr.ru/kanner_2012_5.html